# Present continuous and "going to" form

Tags: present-continuous

I have a question regarding the usage of present continuous and the form "going to".

Which is the right expression between:

1. "We are leaving tomorrow at 9"
2. "We are going to leave tomorrow at 9".

In my opinion both of them are correct, but probably there is a subtle difference.

Comment: Both are correct. The first sounds a little more immediate to me, but that could be just me. No significant practical difference.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter

Comment: Yes, #1 is slightly more decisive.